# Configurable App Modules - Servlet 3 - Enabling/Disabling servlets programmatically

Tags: java, spring, servlets, servlet-filters, servlet-3.0

I have a number of Servlet modules that I would like to be able to enable/disable based on some external property. I'm using Servlet 3.0, currently all the servlets are setup in web.xml.

I know I can programmatically add filters/servlets in Servlet 3.0, however I'm wondering what is the best option and how I should do this based off some .properties file.

I could remove all of the servlets from the web.xml and add them dynamically, however I'm not sure if this will still work as the current base is half using Spring and half not (ideally I'd like to move everything into MVC and possibly use Spring profiles, however thats a while off). The code is being updated, its a bit legacy so some servlets are being wired by Spring so we can at least get DI running throughout the app.

If I go the programmatic route, I want to make sure that if I add a servlet programmatically it will still call the `init(ServletConfig cfg)` method is still called (so I can do Spring wiring of dependencies for the servlet by calling `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext()`). There are a lot of servlets, so it might be rather dense to do it in a Java listener class.

I'm thinking a better approach would be to create a class that creates filters (added at run-time based of the contents of some properties file) to simply make the servlets unreachable.. However I'm not sure how this approach would work.

In a nutshell I want to make the modules within my application configurable. So my question is whats the best way to make servlets configurable? How can I go about doing it?

Thanks!

Comment: the best solution i can think of would be to place your "modules" in some non-default deployment directory and use application-server-specific management APIs to deploy them yourself. not as pretty as what youre looking for though.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that but I really need to keep app server independence. I could change the build to multi wars but this becomes deployment and maintenance hell

Comment: You can restrict access to a Servlet/Module at user level by using a simple mapping table in Database.
When the user login, check the Mapping table for access previleges[which servlets/modules user has access to] 
there by restricting the access to other servlets or modules.

Comment: Yeah thats a good idea. But for this use case I wanted to avoid littering servlets with auth code. I could do this with spring security too. But again there is no user access here. It would be all or none. I.e. the servlet should be inactive....